# How do I configure gitolite3 to use the git account on Ubuntu LTS 16?

Tags: git

The [Ubuntu git help](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html#git-installing-gitolite) provides instructions for configuring gitolite, but Ubuntu 16 LTS delivers gitolite3.  The [gitolite3 install guide](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html#qi) refers the user to their operating system package distribution for installation and initial configuration instructions, but I can't seem to find instructions on the Ubuntu site for gitolite3 configuration.

I installed gitolite3 on Ubuntu 16 with the command:

`apt-get install gitolite3`

I was prompted for the path to my public key file, and provided it.

I was then able to clone the admin repository with the command:

`git clone gitolite3@localhost:gitolite-admin`

How do I configure gitolite3 to use the `git` account instead of the `gitolite3` account with Ubuntu 16?

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer: I'm a newbie to both Ubuntu and gitolite.**

I think your best option is to go back in time and enter a blank admin key when you first run `apt-get install gitolite3`.  This will skip the configuration.  Then you can later configure it by running:

```
dpkg-reconfigure gitolite3
```

This asks for three configuration parameters: system username, repository path and admin's SSH key.  You can provide `git` as the user name.

If travelling back in time is not an option, I have found that it's possible to use `dpkg-reconfigure gitolite3` on an already installed gitolite system to change the username, but only if you are willing to rm/mv/chmod/chown many directories.  This is more than I would feel comfortable doing on a production system and too risky to provide instructions that people might copy & paste without considering how dangerous they are.

Instead, for an already installed gitolite system, you might consider simply renaming the gitolite3 user.

```
usermod gitolite3 --login git
groupmod gitolite3 -n git
```

This will enable the conventional usage of `git clone git@server:myrepo`.

This will also make things a little inconsistent.  For example

```
debconf-show gitolite3
```

will show that the gitolite3 package still thinks the user is `gitolite3`, but in my limited testing, gitolite still works.

Comment: Thought I'd share that I was just able to observe my future self enter `DEBIAN_PRIORITY=low apt-get install gitolite3` and then enter user name, home directory, and ssh key all at once.